# Find an explicit solution to $ -u''= u^2\log |u|$

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, elliptic-pde

It is known that $u=e^{-|x|^2+\frac{n}{2}}$ is a solution to the equation $-\Delta u= u\log |u|~~ \text{in}~ \mathbb{R}^n$, which can be obtain by a limiting process ($p\to 1^+$) of
$-\Delta u=\frac{u|u|^{p-1}-u}{p-1}$. I'd like to obtain an non-trivial explicit solution to $-\Delta u= u^s\log |u|$ for $s>1$ ($u=0$, or $u=1$ is trivial), but have no idea even in the case $n=1$.

Comment: The command of Maple 2023 `pdsolve(-diff(u(x,y),x,x)-diff(u(x,y),y,y)=u(x,y)^(2)*log(abs(u(x,y))));` results in `RootOf(_C1*x + _C2*y + c__3 + Intat(sqrt(_C1^4*c__3 + 2*_C1^2*_C2^2*c__3 + _C2^4*c__3 - 2*PIECEWISE([1/3*_f^3*ln(-_f) - 1/9*_f^3, _f < 0], [0, _f = 0], [1/3*_f^3*ln(_f) - 1/9*_f^3, 0 < _f])*_C1^2 - 2*PIECEWISE([1/3*_f^3*ln(-_f) - 1/9*_f^3, _f < 0], [0, _f = 0], [1/3*_f^3*ln(_f) - 1/9*_f^3, 0 < _f])*_C2^2)/(-_C1^2*c__3 - _C2^2*c__3 + 2*PIECEWISE([1/3*_f^3*ln(-_f) - 1/9*_f^3, _f < 0], [0, _f = 0], [1/3*_f^3*ln(_f) - 1/9*_f^3, 0 < _f])), _f = _Z) - c__4)`.